# Ehcache 2.10.4 not compatible with Spring 4.3.17

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I just upgraded Spring version of my project from Spring-4.2.5 to Spring-4.3.17.RELEASE . Since i update the spring version i am getting below exception :

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Underlying cache cannot be null
   at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.EhcacheDecoratorAdapter.<init> 
  (EhcacheDecoratorAdapter.java:70)
  at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.blocking.BlockingCache.<init> 
  (BlockingCache.java:93)
```

Current version :

Spring -4.317

ehcache - 2.10.4

hibernate3-3.6.6.jar

Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: Please do not truncate stack traces - here with only two frames, both Ehcache, there is not a chance to understand what Spring was doing for example.

Comment: Please add more context; a complete pom.xml would help

Comment: Please post also your persistence.xml (or your hibernate configuration)